# Diffeomorphisms but not of class $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Anyone knows  diffeomorphisms $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ but not of class $C^1$?

or bijective differentiable functions $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ but not of class $C^1$?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any differentiable function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with discontinuous derivative, e.g., $g(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$.

Define $f(x,y)=(x,y+g(x))$ for $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$. Note that the inverse is $f(x,y)=(x,y-g(x))$, so this is indeed a bijective function, differentiable both ways, but not $C^1$.

When $n=1$, the function $Mx+g(x)$ does the job for all sufficiently large $M$. Indeed, its derivative is bounded from below by a positive number, which implies the inverse function exists and is differentiable.

Comment: Thanks for you solution,  just a question what happens when $n=1$?.

Comment: @fel See the edited answer.